# Hide Action Bar while showing Split Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

How can I hide the top Action Bar but show the Split Action Bar using ActionBarSherlock. I would like to have Tabs at the top instead like this:

[image: figure 3]

The Android developer site states the following to hide the action bar but keep the split action bar:

> If you'd like to hide the main action bar at the top, because you're
>   using the built-in navigation tabs along with the split action bar,
>   call setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false) to disable the application icon
>   in the action bar. In this case, there's now nothing left in the main
>   action bar, so it disappears and all that’s left are the navigation
>   tabs at the top and the action items at the bottom, as shown by the
>   second device in figure 3.
>
> https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html#SplitActionBar

In my SherlockFragmentActivity I call the following, however only the app icon and title disappear and the action bar stays like this:

```
    //Hide action bar
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

[image]

Calling `getSupportActionBar().hide()` hides the action bar but also hides the split action bar.

Comment: I've been successfully able to create this very same layout using `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);` and 
`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);` so I'm quite confused as to how you're unable to do so. Would you mind posting your activity source code?

Answer (score 0):

The tabs only roll up into the top action bar if you are using the Tabs provided by ABS. You're not using ViewPager/ViewPagerIndicator for the tabs by any chance are you? (I have this issue currently)